# while sending packet from pcap with scapy it sends application layer value in HEX value

Tags: scapy

```py
        print(f"sending pcap packets to {self.dst_ip}:{self.dst_port}")
        packs = scp.rdpcap(self.pcap)

        new_src_mac = get_mac_address(ip="0.0.0.0")
        new_dst_mac = self.dstmac

        for pkt in packs:
            pkt[scp.Ether].src = new_src_mac
            pkt[scp.Ether].dst = new_dst_mac
            pkt[scp.IP].src= self.src_ip 
            pkt[scp.IP].dst= self.dst_ip
            pkt[scp.TCP].sport = self.src_port
            pkt[scp.TCP].dport = self.dst_port
            pkt[scp.TCP].ack = ack_num
            pkt[scp.TCP].seq = seq_num
            scp.sendp(pkt, iface=self.iface)
```

as seen in above code i am reading pcap packets and sending it to server.

[image]
when i use wireshark it can be seen that packet's data is hexadecimal value

[image]
in original file, packet is shown in the picture.
So my question is how can i send packet like original file instead of with HEX value.

Comment: The two packets are identical.  Can't you see that from the hex dump on the right?  The only difference is that the bottom copy of Wireshark happens to know how to interpret the contents, and the top one does not.

Comment: so the problem is with wireshark. For example I need to check some values on MMS protocol. How can I make wireshark interpret contents? or is there other way to see human readable data

Comment: Wireshark has installable filters, and an MMS filter is available.

Answer (score 0):

It was because I did not use default port, Auto decoding on wireshark works for default ports (MMS: 102) so either I need to send pcap packets on default port or use "Decode As" feature of wireshark to decode manually.